# What is the sensitivity of gradient clipping in Differentially Private SGD?

Tags: differential-privacy

As far as I understand, the [Gaussian Mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_noise_mechanisms#Gaussian_Mechanism) uses the sensitivity of the input function to determine the right amount of noise. In [DP-SGD](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.00133.pdf), said input function is taking the gradient and clipping it to some norm *C*. Then the Gaussian Mechanism is used with *C* as the noise-determining parameter. this should mean the sensitivity of gradient clipping is *C*, i.e. the maximum distance that two clipped gradients obtained from neighboring data sets can have is *C*. But the gradient computation can yield arbitrarily different vectors from neighboring inputs, and the maximum (L2-)distance two arbitrary vectors of (L2-)norm 1 can have is 2! What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notion of *sensitivity* is relative to the definition of *adjacency*.
Sensitivity is the maximum of the absolute distance $|f(d) − f(d)|$ where $d$ and $d'$ are *adjacent* inputs.
Adjacency may be defined in slightly different ways. In [Abadi et al. 2016](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.00133.pdf) it is defined as:

> we say that two of these sets are adjacent if they differ in a single
> entry, that is, if one image-label pair is present in one set
> and absent in the other

It is also the definition used in [Dwork and Roth 2014](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Eaaroth/Papers/privacybook.pdf) (Definition 2.3).

But it is true that some authors define adjacency of $D$ and $D'$ by the fact it is sufficient to change one observation in $D$ to get $D'$. Which can be confusing.

In the case of DP-SGD ([Abadi et al. 2016](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.00133.pdf)), this means that among all possible observations in your universe you add one (one gradient appears) or remove one (one gradient disappears), so 2 outputs from adjacent datasets will differ by $C$ at most (not $2C$).